# Correct git workflow, when should I pull?

Tags: git, workflow, branching-and-merging, git-pull

I have a git workflow, but I am finding that I can't work on feature1 and feature2 at the same time, as they are in different branches. (There will be 2 developers).

My idea is each time I **'git push origin feature-x'** I should **pull** the code back into my master, and then create a new branch. I can then work with what I have already done and build upon that. Otherwise I lose all my work that I have just done, and have to remember what I did. Also other developers are not pulling the newest code they cant work with what I have just added. (Like a new button!)

Once per week we test the testing area, and then push to live.
Then I pull from LIVE with all my changes. is this right?
When should I pull?

[image]